# Hive check elements in array and get index

Tags: arrays, select, filter, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table (students) which has two columns that are arrays.

```
student_list                array<string>                               
present_list                array<string>
```

I know there is a hive function `array_contains(Array<T>, value)` to check if the item is present in the array but what I want to know is the index the item is present in for multiple items.

Example data of student_list is some student id like

```
["1LPT5Q4IE5XC","1SU2QNCG98BC","29V3SAK2Q79Z"]
```

If present_list is

```
["1LPT5Q4IE5XC","29V3SAK2Q79Z"]
```

I want the output as `[0,2]` for that row.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [posexplode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inTable-GeneratingFunctions(UDTF)) to generate the position and value of your list. Something as below:

```
select collect_set(x.pos) as result
from(
 select sl.p1, sl.v1, pl.p2, pl.v2, (sl.v1 = pl.v2) as match
 from table_name
 lateral view posexplode(student_list) sl as p1,v1
 lateral view posexplode(present_list) pl as p2,v2
) as x where match=true
```

Result of the above was `[0,2]`. The idea was to generate a list of positions and then do simple match between the two values in the list. Collect the index positions using `collect_set` function in hive.

One of the downsides of this approach is the cross join of the data when doing posexplode. Using lateral view generates you rows from every array items. This can be an expensive operations to do incase of large volumes.